# Как правильно через декоратор передать значение?

Tags: python, декоратор

Чтобы постоянно не прописывать проверку, решил реализовать это через декоратор:

```
def is_admin(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wraper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('<--| ' + func.__name__ + ' |-->')
        is_admin.dict_user = {   # Вот решил замутить так передачу
            'key': 'value' 
            }
        print('is_admin.dict_user.:', is_admin.dict_user)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wraper
```

а потом непосредственно получить данные во вьюхе

```
@app.route('/page', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@is_admin
def page():
    print('Параметры из <is_admin>: ', is_admin.dict_user) # Вот тут я беру значение
    ...
```

Собственно сам вопрос: на сколько это правильно? Можно ли так реализовывать или это из области г**нокода? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сам `isadmin` (функцию, она же декоратор) лучше ничего не пихать. Так у вас параметры глобально общие становятся (т.к. сама функция - по сути глобальная переменная). В принципе лучше не пихать ничего лишнего не в свой объект, в том числе добавлять "левые" поля функциям.

Лучше добавьте в функцию параметр, который декоратор сам будет заполнять.

```
import functools


def is_admin(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wraper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('<--| ' + func.__name__ + ' |-->')
        dict_user = {
            'key': 'value' 
        }
        print('dict_user:', dict_user)
        return func(*args, dict_user=dict_user, **kwargs)
    return wraper


@is_admin
def page(dict_user):
    print('Получено значение dict_user:', dict_user)


page()
```